# textFieldShouldEndEditing called multiple times

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on a view that has multiple `UITextField` objects.  My view controller serves as the `UITextFieldDelegate`, and I've implemented the `(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method to save and validate the record being displayed.

If the user clicks on the "Done" button after editing an item and the save/validate fails, then a `UIAlertView` is displayed and the user is kept on the `UITextField` that fails validation.

My problem is this -- when a user clicks from the `UITextField` that will fail save/validation onto another of the `UITextField`s, then the `(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method is called multiple times, and the `UIAlertView` pops up multiple times.

Why is `(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` called once when the user clicks "Done" on the keyboard, but called multiple times when the user clicks onto another `UITextField`?

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldEndEditing called by textField with text=%@", textField.text);

    currentItem.nameOrNumber = nameOrNumber.text;

    // Try to save the managed object.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[currentItem managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {        
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Uh Oh!",@"")
                                                             message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"")
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
        [errorAlert release];
        shouldEnd = NO;
    }

    return shouldEnd;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem comes from the order in which textField methods are called when you are editing a textField and directly tap onto another.

If I am not mistaken, it should be something like this (you are editing on A and tap on B)

- `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` for field B
- `textFieldShouldEndEditing` for field A
- `textFieldDidEndEditing` for field A
- `textFieldDidBeginEditing` for field B

So when you are in `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method, textfield B already has become the first responder. So when you make the UIAlertView appear, B loses focus and thus calls `textFieldShouldEndEditing` too!

This also has been a problem for me when I wanted to raise a view when a textField started editing. The solution I found was to create a boolean class variable indicating whether or not I am currently switching from one textField to another. 
I set it to `TRUE` in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and to `FALSE` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. When you're in `textFieldShouldEndEditing`, if it is set to `TRUE` it means the user directly tapped on another textField. Then you just have to find the right way to make your tests only once (maybe shouldEndEditing should return false or something).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to let the `UIAlertView` fake a correct validation and defer the correcting part to a latter time. Something like this :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    double delayInSeconds = 0.;
    self.currentTextField.text = @"Something that won't trigger validation error";
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // do what you need here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you add different tags in each textview and check the tag in the textFieldShouldEndEditing?  Or have I missed the point?

Answer (score 0):

Looks right for me to be called 2 times for each test field.
Why? just think about... had passed to me also and get me headache

You can NOT do some like this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)txtField{

if(i_dont_know){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                    message:@"Message"
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return false;
}

return true;}
```

Is that the UIAlertView show is also trying to resign the editing of text field 
and calling this funcion "textFieldShouldEndEditing:"...

So my way to solve this was to add a member variable called "shouldEndEditing" in the interface delaration, who is true por default.
And after the "textFieldShouldEndEditing:" can be some like this.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)txtField{

if(shouldEndEditing == false)
{
    shouldEndEditing = true;
    return false;
}

if(i_dont_know){
    shouldEndEditing = false;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                    message:@"Message"
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return false;
}

return true;}
```

Good luck...