# textFieldShouldEndEditing delegate method is fired multiple times on a single text field object when instance of UIAlertController is executed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller, uitextfielddelegate

I have a view controller called `LoginViewController` that conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate` and have two text field objects namely `Email` and `Password`. There's an email validation function imposed on the `Email` text field and should the validation fails, an instance of `UIAlertController` will kick in.

Here's the screenshots of the scenes and the code before I continue with my question:

[image: Log In Scene]

[image: Log In Scene with Error]

*ps: There are lots of print statement to allow me to understand the flow of execution*

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    guard self.validateEmail(self.emailTextField.text!) else {
        print("self.presentedViewController: \(self.presentedViewController)")
        if self.presentedViewController == nil {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email Address", message: "Please try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        print("textFieldShouldEndEditing returnin false: \(textField.placeholder!) text field w/ value: \(textField.text!)")
        return false
    }
    print("textFieldShouldEndEditing returning true: \(textField.placeholder!) text field w/ value: \(textField.text!)")
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("textFieldShouldBeginEditing: \(textField.placeholder!) text view")
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("textFieldDidEndEditing: \(textField.placeholder!) text field with value: \(textField.text!)")
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("textFieldDidBeginEditing: \(textField.placeholder!) text field")
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if !(self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && !(self.passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        self.emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if !(self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    print("textFieldShouldReturn: \(textField.placeholder!) text field w/ value: \(textField.text!)")
    return true
}
```

When properly formatted email address is entered in the `Email` text field and focus is moved to the next text field (`Password`) either via the next key or manually tapping on the next text field (`Password`), the following chains of delegate methods occurs as expected (and understood):

`console output:`

Format: [*name of delegate method*: *text field placeholder value (+ text value)*]

```
 textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Email text field
 textFieldDidBeginEditing: Email text field
 textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Password text field
 textFieldShouldEndEditing returning true: Email text field w/ value: abc@abc.co
 textFieldDidEndEditing: Email text field w/ value: abc@abc.co
 textFieldDidBeginEditing: Password text field
 email field is filled
 textFieldShouldReturn: Email text field w/ value: abc@abc.co
```

The issue arises when *incorrect* formatted email address is detected on the `Email` text field. The `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldEndEditing` is invoked **three times** instead of once as instance of `UIAlertController` is presented.

ps: the alert view is only however displayed once on the screen.

`console output:`
Format: [*name of delegate method*: *text field placeholder value (+ text value)*]

```
 textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Email text field
 textFieldDidBeginEditing: Email text field
 textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Password text field

 //1st occurence
 self.presentedViewController: nil
 textFieldShouldEndEditing returnin false: Email text field w/ value: bob

 //2nd occurence
 self.presentedViewController: Optional(<UIAlertController: 0x7f9018662df0>)
 textFieldShouldEndEditing returnin false: Email text field w/ value: bob

 //3rd occurence
 self.presentedViewController: Optional(<UIAlertController: 0x7f9018662df0>)
 textFieldShouldEndEditing returnin false: Email text field w/ value: bob
```

Based on the explanation from this so's thread: ["textFieldShouldEndEditing called multiple times"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3129319/2229062), my understanding is that as focus is about to leave the `Email` text field (the 1st occurence of `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method kicked in), focus is *already* on the `Password` text field thus gaining the first responder status. But, because invalid email is detected, an alert controller is presented and `Password` text field abruptly loses focus and thus triggers `textFieldShouldEndEditing` too. So, I am expecting the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` to only get triggered **twice** (one due to `Email` text field. The other due to `Password` text field) instead of three times (all due to `Email` text field) like this:

```
 textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Email text field
 textFieldDidBeginEditing: Email text field
 textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Password text field

 self.presentedViewController: nil
 textFieldShouldEndEditing returnin false: Email text field w/ value: bob

 self.presentedViewController: Optional(<UIAlertController: 0x7f9018662df0>)
 textFieldShouldEndEditing returnin false: Password text field w/ value: nil
```

But, that's not the case. Can anyone enlighten why my understanding is not correct. Thanks for any pointer provided.

Answer (score 1):

Place your email validation code in

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
```

instead of

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

and before showing alert controller you can also add (if you want to)

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

and on tap **OK** action you can set

```
self.emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Hope this approach will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Haripal, I have tried your suggestion but it produces the following error: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fdbb060b160>  on <Wlkthru.LoginViewController: 0x7fdbb05a7190> which is already presenting (null)`. The only way (that I know) to alleviate this error is to check whether `presentedViewController` is nil. If it's nil, then create the alert controller & action then present it. Then, the error is gone. So I am back to square one.

Comment: I have used same approach to achieve what you are trying to achieve...
Use below code to present alert controller

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}